# WebStorm takes too long for updating changes from perforce

Tags: phpstorm, perforce, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

I'm using integration of Perforce with WebStorm. Everything works fine except that it takes really long for WebStorm to refresh status, so I often have the IDE showing `updating...` label like this:

[image]

Since I don't know how the integration works, I have no way of debugging the issue. Has anyone experienced the problem like this? How can I debug it?

Comment: Are you the admin of your Perforce server? Can you talk to the admin of your Perforce server? Is it **always** slow, or only **sometimes** slow? Is it always **equally** slow? Exactly how long does it take? What platform are you on, and what platform is the server on? What is the networking configuration between you and the server?

Comment: No, I'm not the admin, but I think I can reach him if needed. Please note that p4v, which is also installed on my machine works pretty fast, so I doubt it has something to do with network setup or perforce server configuration. In Webstorm, it takes longer to refresh if the number of files is quite big. For example, for over 300 files I wasn't able to get updates at all since. For a few files, it usually takes about few minutes to refresh. I'm using Windows 10. Unfortunately, don't know much about networking configuration on the server side.